# Java - Cast object read from properties file

Tags: java, class, casting, properties

I'm saving a properties file by using reflection to loop through a class's fields one by one and saving the field's name and value to the file.

Now I need to create this class again and give it the values stored in the properties file. I came up with this. returnEntity is the new instance of the class.

```
for (Field f : returnEntity.getClass().getFields())
        {
            Class  fieldType = f.getType();
            String fieldName = f.getName();

            f.set(returnEntity, fieldType.cast(properties.get(fieldName)));
        }
```

It works up until it has to cast the field to the type "Int". For some reason it throws a ClassCastException then. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It says "int" when I look at the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that int is not a class, like, float, char, short, long, they are all primitives. To make this work you need to cast to Integer, then use intValue();

```
Integer(myInt).intValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

A Properties only contains values of type String. There is no way a String can be cast to an int.

I have the feeling that you're reinventing the wheel. You could serialize your object in a binary form, using Java native serialization, or use an XML marshaller to serialize your bean as XML.

Or if you want to read/write from/to a Properties, why not simply provide two methods, and avoid reflection:

```
public toProperties() {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("foo", foo);
    p.setProperty("bar", Integer.toString(bar);
    p.setProperty("zim.blam", zim.getBlam());
}

public static Config fromProperties(Properties p) {
    Config c = new Config();
    c.foo = p.getProperty("foo");
    c.bar = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("bar"));
    c.zim = new Zim();
    c.zim.setBlam(p.getProperty("zim.blam"));
}
```

Comment: I'm doing it like this so that the class can be modified outside of the program. It doesn't need to be in a binary format.

Comment: And why use reflection for this? Why not use two methods to instanciate the object from properties, and write properties from the object?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean?

Comment: Hello @JBNizet could you where is this Config class coming from?  java.io final class ObjectInputFilter.Config ?