# Avoid multiple castings of java properties (String) to Integer Double

Tags: java, casting, properties

I am looking for a way to reduce the castings of properties from java Properties to Numeric such as Integer, Double and if possible even a class that might casting directly for instance `Integer[]`.

Say I have multiple properties and must pass for instantiation many times and I wish to use a class that parses and casts only once.

```
Properties mogaProps = parseProperties("mogabcpu/moga");
for (int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    NSGA2Runner GA = new NSGA2Runner(Integer.valueOf(mogaProps.getProperty(
            "NUMINITIALCHROMOSSOMES")), Integer.valueOf(mogaProps.getProperty(
            "NUMCHROMOSOMES")),
            Double.valueOf(mogaProps.getProperty(
                    "MUTATIONRATE")), Double.valueOf(mogaProps.getProperty(
            "CROSSOVERRATE")),
            parseStringTo1DArray(mogaProps.getProperty("NUMITERATIONS"))
}
```

Is there a better alternative avoiding the use of a custom class to specifically hold all potential different data types attributes?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934719/java-cast-object-read-from-properties-file) However I could not find this Config Class dependency.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to reduce the castings of properties

You are [parsing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), not [casting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion). The `.valueOf` calls are creating new values by interpreting the meaning held within text (parsing) rather than reshaping an existing value (casting). But not a useful distinction in the context of your Question, just FYI.

> Say I have multiple properties and must pass for instantiation many times and I wish to use a class that parses and casts only once.

If the properties are not changing at runtime, just instantiate your configuration object (a `NSGA2Runner` object in your case, your `GA`) once. Pass that object around to the other methods and objects that need the information.

In your example code with the `for` loop, if your real code is processing the properties once and then using that data 10,000 times, move your `GA =` line to outside the loop.

By the way, if you are assigning an object once only, mark `GA` as `final`. That keyword obstructs any inadvertent attempt to make that variable point to any other object.

> reduce the castings of properties from java Properties to Numeric such as Integer, Double

Your data is stored as text in a `Properties`. You need to work with that data as numbers, not text. So there is no getting around the chore of parsing that text into numbers.

I am not sure why you are concerned about this. Perhaps performance is your concern? Such parsing is quick and easy. Not a significant impact on performance unless you are often processing millions of such values. Do a bit of micro benchmarking to see for yourself.

> Is there a better alternative avoiding the use of a custom class to specifically hold all potential different data types attributes?

Defining a class is the appropriate way to gather together related parts of information in an object-oriented language like Java.

If your data is read-only, then you might want to use the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature in Java 16 and later. A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You merely need to declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
public record NSGA2Runner( int numberOfInitialChromosomes , int numberOfChromosomes , double mutationRate , double crossoverRate , int[] numberOfIterations ) {}
```

Comment: _"If you are assigning an object once only, mark GA as final."_ - This will only guarantee that the reference `GA` cannot point to a different object. It has no effect on the values stored in the referenced object.  You make those immutable by not providing setter methods.

Comment: @JimGarrison Exactly why I carefully chose the wording “assigning an object once only”, and did not say immutable.